# Exception with ngx-malihu-scrollbar in angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, scrollbar

I have used ngx-malihu-scrollbar in my angular 2 project but when I move to other page I got below error.

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'autoUpdate' of undefined
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use MalihuScrollbarService for activate the scrollbar. Use of malihu-scrollbar directive 'll throw the above menitoned issue.

Visit:https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-malihu-scrollbar